# Symfony2 The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: php, json, ajax, symfony, twig

I am trying render a modal window dynamic, the problem is when return my response Json, i get the next error:

```
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.
```

This is my controller:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

//Some Code...

public function detallesAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $articulo = $em->getRepository("FicherosBundle:Articulo")->find($id);

    $html = $this->render('FicherosBundle:Articulos:detalles.html.twig', array(
            "articulo"     => $articulo
    ))->getContent();

     $response = new Response(json_encode(array(
            "detalles" =>  $html
     )));
     $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

     return $response;
}
```

And this my template detalles.html.twig:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Detalles</h4>
    <small class="font-bold">En esta ventana se ve reflejada toda la información del articulo.</small>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    Hello world
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
</div>
```

And this is my call to AJAX from index.html.twig:

```
$('.detalles').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var url = Routing.generate('articulos_detalles', { id: id });
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) {
            $(".modal-content").html(response.detalles);
            $("#myModal2").modal("show");
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    })
});
```

Where is the problem? :/

Comment: what you get in `$html` ? try dump. seems like you getting boolean in `Response.`

Comment: `json_encode` return a false when it fails. Also you can condense all of that response headers stuff by using `JsonResponse`.

Comment: Yes, I have something wrong in detalles.html.twig ...: /

Comment: just on a sidenote, better to use `return new JsonResponse($array,$code)`. cleaner and easier to debug.

Answer (score 4):

It seems your html cannot be encoded correctly in json.

Also you should directly use the `renderView` method and `JsonResponse` to render it without specifying headers/encoding json manually.
This will prevent you from errors like you have now using a custom Response.

It should be :

```
$html = $this->renderView('FicherosBundle:Articulos:detalles.html.twig', array(
    "articulo"     => $articulo
))->getContent();

return new JsonResponse($html);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this work with renderView and JsonResponse, but I need pass a array.Often I need to pass multiple parameters to the array of json

Comment: Show me an example of what you want return and I will try to answer you